# How to export property of a interface/Object like Javascript in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

As we known, the commonJS module's `exports` is a JS Object commonly. We can access the specific method easily like `const { methodA } = require('module').`

How can we impl the `.d.ts`(types declaration file), allowing the typescript user to enjoy the similar import experience?
We hope to do like that:

```js
// JavaScript
const sdk = require('module')
sdk.methodA(params)
// Or
const { methodA } = require('module')
methodA(params)

// Typescript also can be:
import sdk from 'module'
sdk.methodA(params)
// Or
import { methodA } from 'module'
methodA(params)
```

That is my current impl:

```
export * from './interface' // a .d.ts file that includes all interface, is it necessnary exported to users?
interface Instance {
  methodA: (params: anthorInterface) => Promise<ResponseInterface>
}
declare const sdk: Instance
export default sdk
```

But the syntax `import { methodA } from 'method'` doesn't work, though, the default behavior works fine.

Could you give me any suggestions? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Where and how is `methodA` declared?

Comment: methodA is declared in a JS module. Like that: `module.exports: { methodA: async (params) => 1}`

Comment: `import` isn't a TypeScript thing and destructuring assignment is very different semantically from named imports. You need to decide if you are _writing_ CommonJS or ESM code.

Comment: the original project is written by Pure JavaScript(Node.js Module). I want to write a `.d.ts` file to support the use in TypeScript. What's my confusion is the content described in the topic

Comment: i found if i drop other `export`, I can use `export = sdk` directly. But it will drop all exported interface(maybe useful in development). Are there any other ways? Thx.

Comment: ES Modules are a JavaScript thing so when you say your project is written in pure JavaScript, it doesn't matter. Get that into your head.

Comment: ok. thank you. i will bear it in mind. it is  written in commonJS,  not a esm module

Comment: Then you should use `export = sdk` in your `.d.ts` file. If you want to export additional types, place them in a `namespace` also named `sdk`. Declaration merging.

Comment: Thx. I will have a try